# appendLine in cell next to the previous value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this function that executes on a button click.

```
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder csvconten = new StringBuilder();
        csvconten.AppendLine(comboBox1.Text).AppendLine(comboBox2.Text);
        string csvpath = "cross_check2.csv";
        File.AppendAllText(csvpath, csvconten.ToString());
    }
```

In this block of code:

```
 csvconten.AppendLine(comboBox1.Text).AppendLine(comboBox2.Text);
```

I want the comoBox2.Text value to appear next to comboBox1.Text. currently it keeps going under comboBox2.Text. How do I get it beside it in the next cell?
Let me repeat, beside it i the next cell not in the same cell. it would be comboBox2.Text in cell A and comboBox2.Text in cell B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing a csv file, your line of code appends it as a new line

This will append a single line separated by a comma.

```
csvconten.AppendFormat("{0},{1}\r\n",comboBox1.Text,comboBox2.Text);
```

Comment: What if I add 3 more values?

Comment: would this be right:  `csvconten.AppendFormat("{0},{1}, {2},{3}, {4}, {5}\r\n",comboBox1.Text,comboBox2.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Use Only Append in this case. If the should be different columns of the csv add the separator of the csv instead of " ".

```
csvconten.AppendLine(comboBox1.Text).Append(" " + comboBox2.Text);
```

Comment: This stays in the same cell.

Comment: @Jevon okay what is your separator ?